# Copy constructor copies pointer first, then dereferences it to obtain "deep" copy

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I'm looking at the following (bad) example code in http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c22-make-default-operations-consistent:

```
class Silly {   // BAD: Inconsistent copy operations
    class Impl {
        // ...
    };
    shared_ptr<Impl> p;
public:
    Silly(const Silly& a) : p{a.p} { *p = *a.p; }   // deep copy
    Silly& operator=(const Silly& a) { p = a.p; }   // shallow copy
    // ...
};
```

The authors try to illustrate the mismatch between copy c'tor and copy assignment, but I'm wondering if the code is flawed in an other way.

Does the "deep copy" constructor make sense? It looks like on entering the body, `p` will be the same as `a.p` and the self-assignment doesn't do anything (at best).

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, that's just a load of nonsense.

Presumably that's the point of the example, though I'm not convinced it's a great example.

Otherwise it's possible that the authors meant:

```
Silly(const Silly& a) : p{std::make_shared<Impl>()} { *p = *a.p; }
```

or:

```
Silly(const Silly& a) : p{std::make_shared<Impl>(*a.p)} {}
```

Or somesuch.

Comment: Would it be possible to move `p=a.p` from the initializer list to after the dereferencing and copying of its content?

Comment: @Pavel The code will compile if that's what you mean by "possible". But why would you do that? What's the goal?

Answer (score 0):

```
Silly(const Silly& a) : p{a.p} { *p = *a.p; }
```

Will, in addition to copying the underlying shared_pointer, make a copy of the value pointed by it. What concerns me is that `shared_ptr<T>::operator*` actually returns `T&`, our assignment will therefore change the value for the control block and actually accomplish nothing.

But then again, the intent was not to demonstrate actual deep copy but provide inconsistent copy operations.

Deep copy of a `shared_ptr` would look like this

```
Silly(const Silly& a) : p{make_shared<Impl>(*a.p)} {}
```

Comment: _"our assignment will therefore change the value for the control block and actually accomplish nothing"_ Can you expand on this? It accomplishes nothing because you assign a thing to itself.

Comment: I believe it would just do the equivalent to `a = a`. Copies of `shared_ptr` *share* the same control block, that's why assigning the copied value would be pointless.

Comment: Okay, good, that's correct. Not sure what you meant with the whole `T&` thing, didn't seem relevant or seemed like you were talking about something else perhaps. The phrase "change the value for the control block" seems not quite right. Ah well